# if statment not working properly in android

Tags: java, android, if-statement, trim

hello guys im newbie in android i want just to change the text view text if the caculate value between 18 or 25  i used if statment but there is no results 
any idea sometimes if i removed one of the >its worked but only for biggest value

```
public class GB extends ActionBarActivity {
  ImageView im1;
  EditText mEditText1,mEditText2;
  TextView mTextView,m5;
  Button mButton;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_GB);
    im1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    mEditText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    mEditText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    m5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
          case R.id.button1:
        }
        String word2 = mEditText2.getText().toString();
        String word = mEditText1.getText().toString();
        if (word.trim().equals("")){ 
          mEditText1.setError("Insert Hight");
        }
        else if (word2.trim().equals("")){
          mEditText2.setError("Insert Wight");
        } else{
          calculate();
        }
      }
    });
  }

  public void calculate(){
    Double value1 = Double.parseDouble(mEditText1.getText().toString());
    Double value2 = Double.parseDouble(mEditText2.getText().toString());
    Double calculatedValue = value1/(value2*value2)*10000;
    calculatedValue = Math.round(calculatedValue*10)/10.0d;
    mTextView.setText(calculatedValue.toString());
    if (mTextView.getText().toString().trim().length() <10 && mTextView.getText().toString().trim().length() >18) {
      im1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.s1);
      m5.setText("low");
    } else if (mTextView.getText().toString().trim().length() <18 && mTextView.getText().toString().trim().length() >25) {
      im1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.s3);
      m5.setText("Best");
    } else if (mTextView.getText().toString().trim().length() <25 && mTextView.getText().toString().trim().length() >100) {
      im1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.s3);
      m5.setText("over");
    }         
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if a value is in an interval, you have to write it as follows:

```
if(myvalue > lowerbound && myvalue < upperbound )
```

The following code probably does what you want.

```
  public void calculate(){
    Double value1 = Double.parseDouble(mEditText1.getText().toString());
    Double value2 = Double.parseDouble(mEditText2.getText().toString());
    Double calculatedValue = value1/(value2*value2)*10000;
    calculatedValue = Math.round(calculatedValue*10)/10.0d;
    mTextView.setText(calculatedValue.toString());
    if (calculatedValue >= 10 && calculatedValue < 18) {
      im1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.s1);
      m5.setText("low");
    } else if (calculatedValue >= 18 && calculatedValue < 25) {
      im1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.s3);
      m5.setText("Best");
    } else if (calculatedValue >= 25 && calculatedValue < 100) {
      im1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.s3);
      m5.setText("over");
    }         
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for help but the value already checked but itsn't getting any results in if statment

Comment: Do you want to check the value of the number in the textview, or the length of the number in the textview?

Comment: i want to check if the value of the number was between another two numbers like i want to check if textview value  between 1 and 20

Answer (score 2):

An integer value cannot be smaller than 18 and bigger than 25 at the same time.

Instead of

```
if (mTextView.getText().toString().trim().length() <18 && mTextView.getText().toString().trim().length() >25)
```

Use this one if you want to check a value between 18 and 25.

```
if (mTextView.getText().toString().trim().length() > 18 && mTextView.getText().toString().trim().length() < 25)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Your  switch statement here is useless, You have already set click listener to button and again you are trying to check if it's the same button clicked.
2. It would good if you check if the value entered is numeric.
3. when you use if, else if and else - one and only one will be executed, which ever full fills the statement will be executed and rest of the code won't execute, say for instance have a look at the following:

> ```
>    if( a > b){
>      //show A is bigger than b;
>      } else if ( a == b){
>      // show A equals to b 
>     } else{
>     // b > a
>      }
> ```

Here,

```
 if (word.trim().equals("")){//if this conditions works, code won't go to test else if or else statement. 
          mEditText1.setError("Insert Hight");
        }
        else if (word2.trim().equals("")){
          mEditText2.setError("Insert Wight");
        } else{
          calculate();
        }
```

4. The way you are checking the values is wrong, the statement will be always false, as 1. you are testing if the value if < 10 and at the same time you are test if the value is > 18, one of which be false for sure.

   if(mTextView.getText().toString().trim().length() <10 && mTextView.getText().toString().trim().length() >18)

Comment: ok now i deleted all the if statment  in calculate  how to check if the mtextview value between 2 numbers

Comment: consider mTextView.getText().toString().trim().length() to a number,  here if(mTextView.getText().toString().trim().length() <10 && mTextView.getText().toString().trim().length() >18) you are using logical && to check, so both of the conditions will be matched i.e. if the length is less than 10 and length is greater than 18, which is not possible. Say  mTextView.getText().toString().trim().length() is 9, in that case first condition matches that is less than 10 length but the second condition checks if the length is greater than 18 which is not and hence the code wont execute.

Comment: so what if it greater than 10 and less than 18

Comment: first condition which is <10 will be false and hence it won't work out.

Comment: the problem is  that the numbers between the 10 and 18 would be like 2.48 so